# Python scripts and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Good day!

I have a question annoying me. I setup Apache server/MySQL/PhpMyAdmin on my PC. And i'd like to write some scrips on python3 to work with database. I setup my db on localhost. But now the local network has another one computer.

I wish my friend could access the database through my ip. like (http :// 192.168.xx.xx / pma). 
and now it works!

My friend loves python too. And there is a problem: When he's run script, python waits 30 sec and:

```
"Can't connect to MySQL server on %r (%s)" % (self.host, e))
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.
xx.xx' ([WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected part
y did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection fai
led because connected host has failed to respond)")
```

There peace of code to connect:

```
import pymysql   
con = pymysql.connect(host='192.168.xx.xx', user='root', passwd='xxx', db='test')
cur = con.cursor()
print(con)
```

Help my friend to work with my database! 
Thanks you!

Comment: Please check mysql config. Have you enable access of database from give ip ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give [remote access to your `mysql` database](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html).

Then give grant to your user.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```